# When implementing a custom $exceptionHandler in angularJS, how do I preserve default log?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a custom angularJS `$exceptionHandler` (to send client exceptions to my server) :

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
  return function(exception, cause) {
    //custom handling of the exception
    //...
  };
});
```

How do I preserve default console log ?

Answer (score 0):

Default log can be preserved by using `$log` :

```
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', function($log) {
  return function(exception, cause) {
    //custom handling of the exception
    //...
    $log.error.apply($log, arguments);
  };
}]);
```

More info on [this blog post](http://engineering.talis.com/articles/client-side-error-logging/).